# Best way to store AWS IoT credentials on a serverless node instance?

Tags: node.js, aws-iot, cloud9, serverless, aws-codestar

My existing locally hosted server loads its iot identity + credentials like so:

```
function initIot() {
  var device = awsIot.device({
     keyPath: './iot_credentials/ident-private.pem.key',
    certPath: './iot_credentials/ident-certificate.pem.crt',
      caPath: './iot_credentials/rootca.pem',
    clientId: 'iot-server-1',
        host: endpoint
  });
```

..and I don't commit the private key & cert anywhere.  It lives securely on the server disk.

How would I securely migrate this to serverless cloud9 setup running on codestar?  Assuming I trust my AWS team, can I just store it in the project's files?

Answer (score 1):

Keep out the sensitive data from code regardless of the IDE. There are few options you can consider.

- You can use a environmental variable in Lambda to store the file content.
- Sore it in S3 private bucket with restricted access and retrieve it in code.
- Use DevOps to append the config at CI/CD pipeline.
- You can also use AWS KMS to store the sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

As long as those files are properly restricted from public access, I think that's fine.